# SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild doesn't run

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using Jenkins to run SonarQube for my .Net project(C#).

Visual Studio:2015
MsBuils: 14
Jenkins on Linux (1.624)
SonarServer on Linux (Sonar Version 6.0)

Job Config:
SonarQube Scanner for MsBuilds- Begin analysis

Project key:
Project Name:
Proj Version:

Build a Visual Studio Project or Solution using MSBuild:
MsBuild Version : MsBuild 4.6
MsBuild File: CI.Sln
Command Line Arguments: /p:Configuration=Release /target:Build

SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild- End Analysis

I can generate report for Visual Studio 2015 and post to Sonar Server but when i try to run in Jenkins job its doesn't work.

Error:

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME exists but does not point to a valid Java home folder. No "\bin\java.exe" file can be found there.
>
> The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
>
> 08:42:40.676  Creating a summary markdown file...
>
> Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
>
> ERROR: Execution of SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild failed (exit code 1)

I have Windows Server as an agent and out put of Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]

C:\Windows\System32>echo %JAVA_HOME%

C:\Program Files\Java\jre8

Java Home Variable Path:C:\Program Files\Java\jre8

Please let me know how would I make jenkins job work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a rookie mistake.

This was an issue related to JDK, as i installed JRE but not JDK. I have installed JDK and add the path to Jenkins master and Jenkins job. Ran the job and horraaayyyy, Its working now.

Comment: It should be working with only the JRE. I guess something was not properly configured.

Comment: I had JRE before but it didn't work. I dont know what was the configuration issue but once i installed JDK and add the path (i also added the path for JRE before) it starts working.

Comment: I am glad to know you solved this problem and thanks for sharing the solution. Please mark it as an answer, It will be very beneficial for other community members who have the similar questions